# SQL Select i dunno what exactly mean

Tags: mysql, sql

i have sql table like this

```
pets    playstart   endstart
cat     12:10       12:50
dog     13:10       13:50
lion    14:10       14:50
```

if i select 13:35 
result **dog**
how create sql query for this command?

Comment: What data type in date column?

Comment: Try to make your question title more closely reflect your actual question. "i dunno what exactly mean" isn't very useful for searching on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to the question. A select statement is a statement that aims at retrieving some data. SQL was invented to be a human readable way of interacting with databases. As such you can almost phrase your query as a question.

In this case your question would be "What pet would be played with at 13:35?".

Provided the table is guaranteed to have none-overlapping "playstart" and "playend" values this should work (I don't know what the name of your table is so I've used "yourtable" to represent that).

```
select pets from yourtable where playstart <='13:35' and playend >='13:35'
```

Comment: Assuming the playstart and playend columns are time data type, you can also use the syntax `SELECT pets FROM yourtable WHERE '13:35' between playstart and playend;`

Comment: Hi @Erlina can you please mark my answer as accepted if it has helped you out? Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one, I hope this will works for you

select pets from pets where playstart >= '13:10' and endstart <= '13:50'